# Tensor product rank and dual spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

I am only desiring a **hint** as I just have nothing to go off of for this question.

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces. Given that there is an isomorphism, $$f:W\otimes V^* \to \text{Hom}(V,W):w\otimes v^* \mapsto (v \mapsto v^*(\cdot)w),$$
show that for $\forall t \in W\otimes V^*$ we have that:$$\text{rank } t = \text{rank }f(t).$$

---

I don't really know how to approach this, let alone figure out the rank for a generic element $f(t)$, or what it looks like (I would think we would have to create a matrix for it since we are referring to the rank of a linear function, perhaps that means I should first assume a basis for $V$ and $W$?). Perhaps there is a gap in my knowledge. I am grateful for any hints, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the rank of a tensor $t$ is given by is defined to be the smallest $k$ such that we can find $v_1,\dots,v_k \in V$ and $w_1,\dots,w_k \in W$ satisfying
$$
t = \sum_{j=1}^k w_j \otimes v_j
$$
The key insight to this problem, however, is that the rank of a map can be defined similarly.  The rank of a map $\phi \in \operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$ is *defined* to be $\dim \phi(V)$.  However, we can define the rank of $\phi$ to be the smallest $k$ such that we can find $v_1^*,\dots,v_k^* \in V^*$ and $w_1,\dots,w_k \in W$ satisfying
$$
\phi = \sum_{j=1}^k w_j v_j^* 
$$
The key to one proof that the definitions are equivalent:

- Every map has a singular value decomposition (in particular, rank-1 maps can be written in the form $w v^*$ for some $v \in V$ and $w \in W$).
- $\operatorname{rank}(A + B) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)$

Once you have this, it suffices to note that $f$ gives a (linear) bijection between simple tensors and rank-1 maps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint! If I have any more questions later about it I will be sure to ask.

Comment: A question: subsequent to proving that the two definitions of $\text{rank }\phi$ are equal, it is necessary to prove that there is no smaller sum (and thus rank) after using the bijection, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. That's what the rank inequality is for.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  No, it is not necessary to prove that there is no smaller sum.  It suffices to note that $f^{-1}$ takes a sum of rank-1 maps to a sum of rank-1 tensors.